# Create KML file from Google Earth URL

Tags: google-maps, download, google-earth, google-my-maps, kml

I've been emailed the following https://earth.google.com/web/@30.0867484,-97.29304982,148.9215598a,284.21410691d,31.95361314y,0h,0t,0r

Is there a way to turn this into a KML file?

I have downloaded Google Earth Pro, but don't see a way to open this URL using it. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- go to **[My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/)**

  [image: 0]
- click on **<kbd>`+ CREATE A NEW MAP`</kbd>** button
- copy coordinates from your link **`30.0867484,-97.29304982`**
- paste them into the search bar and hit **<kbd>`Enter`</kbd>** key
- optional: zoom in and change to satellite view
- click on **3 dots**
- select **Export to KML/KMZ**
- tick the **KML instead of KMZ** checkbox and **Download**

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you/ If you have time I have a bounty at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56201017/google-earth-to-google-maps